# C# Serialization: save List with objects of type Action to file

Tags: c#, object, serialization

I have problem with serialization.

My list look like :

```
 public List<Action> functions = new List<Action>();
```

Later i just add objects to list by :

```
functions.Add(waypoint1);
```

my button to serialize look like :

```
 private async void metroButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // save wpts button
        {
            string dir = @"c:\temp";
            string serializationFile = Path.Combine(dir, "wpts.bin");
            //serialize
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(serializationFile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

                bformatter.Serialize(stream, functions);
            }

        }


void Waypoint1()
{
Console.WriteLine("Im first waypoint");
}
```

When i try just save to file i have an error:
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

What should i add here just don't know searches a lot of forums and still don't know. Please be patient for newbies in c#.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you show an example of Waypoint1 action? what should it do, And why do you want to serialize it?

Comment: @ up its not important thing what this doing but i edited my main for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all objects could be serialized. Action is not serializable.

You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656716.aspx) or read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947881/asp-net-can-a-delegate-action-be-serialized-into-control-state)

In some cases you can do it in a simple way.
Instead of having List of Action you can have List of MyAction. 
Where MyAction is:

```
public class MyAction
{
    //there could be several fields with data for Execute method.
    //Type of this fields should be serializable.
    public string DataForExecute { get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        //Do all you need here...
    }
}
```

You can even can inherit from this class and have a hierarchy. but it makes serialization/deserialization more complex.

Comment: So i just need to create a serializable  "something" . What can i use just to take the same what i have now in my list. ( Luist of method objects. )

Comment: @Michael it is not an easy task to serialize deligate. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1947932/4627031) LBushkin propose some general approaches and describe why it is not work in generel case.

Comment: OK i understand but can i use something else to get list of method objects without using delegate?

Comment: @Michael well, the easiest way is to create a serializable class MyAction which will have Execure method and all data it need for execution in properties with public getter and setter, and have a list of this objects. if it is appliable in your case. I can edit my answer and add en example if you want.

Comment: Chepikov  Yes please do it.